# Number of lambda calls when called many nested calls are executed

Tags: amazon-web-services, design-patterns, aws-lambda

If I call one lambda function with one request, but within that function, there are three calls made to different functions then would this count as 4 calls or is it just one call since its based on one request?

So if the count is 4 then (from economic stand point) wouldnt it be better if one writes one long function instead of many small functions, despite it being ill advised from design pattern stand point?

Comment: *"there are three calls made to different functions"* Define what you mean by "calls made to different functions."  Maybe a little code example.

Answer (score 5):

Every invocation of a Lambda function counts.  It doesn't matter whether you call it from the console, from a CLI, from an event source, or from another Lambda function it will count as invocation.

Personally, I would focus on writing my Lambda functions in a way that makes sense and allowed me to use them effectively.  If you find your costs are a factor later, you can always adjust then.

Comment: +1 this; the thing that left me unclear about the original question was whether OP was trying to avoid using "functions" (methods, procedures, subroutines -- you get the idea -- branching within the same file, for example)  within lambda functions, and instead, writing one long block of code (due to the multiple possible interpretations of the word "function," going on an assumption that such branching incurred a cost). I may be off base, reading that ambiguity into the question when it wasn't really there.